# Resonant converter - negative voltage on resonant capacitor

Tags: dc-dc-converter, resonant-converter

I built/designed a one switch resonant converter with a simple integrative feedback control only. I found they after some (increased) loading the resonant capacitor becomes charged to negative voltage (-5 V). The capacitor I am using is an electrolytic type and after few minutes it becomes little hot (50 degrees C)

Is it harmful to use electrolytic capacitors with this (-5 V) condition?

This converter is a single polarity switched (not full reversed like in two switch types) so it happens only if R_load is small and not dump the C4/L2 output oscillation enough.

**Capacitor voltage**
[image: Capacitor voltage]

**Schematic:**
[image]

How can I avoid the L1 reverse current in the MOSFET path through its body diode? For now I am using a series diode (D2) which works well but causes losses. Should I use an SCR or a BJT instead of the MOSFET to block the reverse current?

**L1 current**
[image]

Comment: What's the maximum ripple current that flows through the capacitor? You certainly can't use a polar electrolytic cap there but I need to know the ripple current in order to recommend a better-suited capacitor type.

Comment: @Jonathan S. The peak current when charging through L1 is 4A. When discharging through L2 is much less due to L2 high inductance.

Comment: Electrolytic capacitor in a resonant tank sounds like a recipe for disaster. Also, are you forced to develop an SMPS with a non-DSO?

Answer (score 1):

-5V will kill a polarized electrolytic capacitor and 4A ripple current will too. Don't do this, use a film capacitor (possibly multiple in parallel) instead.

The -5V will cause the capacitor to dissolve its internal components and build up pressure in the can, which will lead to venting or an explosion after prolonged use.

The 4A ripple current is the cause of the excessive heating. This will dry out the capacitor (or cause an explosion too when it gets way too hot).

All in all, your electrolytic cap will most likely degrade or fail within a few dozen hours of use.